# Accessing IDWriteTextFormat instead of creaing new (FW1FontWrapper line spacing)

Tags: c++, reference, directx, directx-11

I'm using `FW1FontWrapper` library to wrap the font using in my DirectX 11 C++ application.

I want to change the line spacing (distance between two lines of text) in the text rendered with `FW1FontWrapper`.

I know that in DirectX I can use to it `IDWriteTextFormat::SetLineSpacing(DWRITE_LINE_SPACING_METHOD_UNIFORM, 30.0f, 20.0f)`.

Unfortunatelly, I don't know how to access the right `IDWriteTextFormat` structure.

I have tried to:

```
HRESULT hResult = FW1CreateFactory(FW1_VERSION, &FW1Factory);
hResult = FW1Factory->CreateFontWrapper(device, L"Arial", &fontWrapper);

//my attemp - first get the IDWriteFactory
IDWriteFactory *pDWriteFactory;
hResult = fontWrapper->GetDWriteFactory(&pDWriteFactory);

//and now the IDWriteTextFormat 
IDWriteTextFormat *pTextFormat;
hResult = pDWriteFactory->CreateTextFormat(L"Arial", NULL, 
    DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL, DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL, 
    DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL, 10.0f, L"", &pTextFormat);
pTextFormat->SetLineSpacing(DWRITE_LINE_SPACING_METHOD_UNIFORM, 100.f, 20.0f);
```

I guess it doesn't work, because that way I create and modify the **new** `IDWriteTextFormat`, not the one that will have affect on the rendering by:

```
fontWrapper->DrawString(
   context,
   s2ws(content).c_str(),// String
   fontSize,// Font size
   startTextPosition.getX(),// X position
   startTextPosition.getY(),// Y position
   color,// Text color, 0xAaBbGgRr
   FW1_RESTORESTATE// Flags (for example FW1_RESTORESTATE to keep 
        //context states unchanged)
 );
```

So, how access the right `IDWriteTextFormat` (the one that when I will modify, will have impact on the rendering; not the new one)?

As far as I know `FW1FontWrapper` has no own method to set line spacing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source code of the FW1FontWrapper module, you can see that `DrawString` internally uses a default `IDWriteTextFormat` that you can't access.

The solution is to use `DrawTextLayout` instead of `DrawString`.

To do this (using your variable names), first create the factory and `IFW1FontWrapper` as in your existing code:

```
HRESULT hResult = FW1CreateFactory(FW1_VERSION, &FW1Factory);
hResult = FW1Factory->CreateFontWrapper(device, L"Arial", &fontWrapper);
```

Then get the DWrite factory and create the `IDWriteTextFormat` with the required line spacing (again, this is your existing code):

```
// get the DirectWrite factory used by the font-wrapper
IDWriteFactory *pDWriteFactory;
hResult = fontWrapper->GetDWriteFactory(&pDWriteFactory);

// create an IDWriteTextFormat and set line spacing
IDWriteTextFormat *pTextFormat;
hResult = pDWriteFactory->CreateTextFormat(L"Arial", NULL, 
    DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL, DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL, 
    DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL, 10.0f, L"", &pTextFormat);
pTextFormat->SetLineSpacing(DWRITE_LINE_SPACING_METHOD_UNIFORM, 100.f, 20.0f);
```

Next, create a `IDWriteTextLayout` for your string (using your variable names) and using the `IDWriteTextFormat` created above:

```
// create a DirectWrite text layout for the string
// using the above IDWriteTextFormat 
IDWriteTextLayout *pTextLayout;
unsigned int stringLength = s2ws(content).size();
hResult = pDWriteFactory->CreateTextLayout(
    s2ws(content).c_str(),
    stringLength,
    pTextFormat,
    0.0f,
    0.0f,
    &pTextLayout);
```

Set the font size in the `IDWriteTextLayout` object:

```
// set the required font size
DWRITE_TEXT_RANGE allText = {0, stringLength};
pTextLayout->SetFontSize(fontSize, allText);
```

And finally, draw the text using `DrawTextLayout` (again, using your variable names) :

```
// draw the text
fontWrapper->DrawTextLayout(
    context,
    pTextLayout,
    startTextPosition.getX(),
    startTextPosition.getX(),
    color,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    FW1_RESTORESTATE);

// tidy up interfaces
pTextLayout->Release();
pTextLayout = NULL;
```

I may have made some wrong assumptions from your existing code, but you can see how you can use your own `IDWriteTextFormat` via an `IDWriteTextLayout` instance and then use `DrawTextLayout` instead of `DrawString`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for very in-deep anserw :-)

Comment: Passing the fontSize to CreateTextFormat (currently 10.0f) makes the pTextLayout->SetFontSize call redundant.

Comment: are there methods to render multiple colored string also?